# How to show $[F(a):F[a^4+a^2+1]$ is finite.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I have an element $a$ in an extension field $F$.

I'm asked if it is true that $a^4+a^2+1$ is algebraic over $F$ if and only if $a$ is algebraic over $F$. I know that if I can show $[F(a):F(a^4+a^2+1)]$ has a finite degree that $a$ is algebraic and I'll be good. How can I show that it is finite?

Comment: All you need to do is write down an explicit polynomial $P(X)\in F(a^4 + a^2 + 1)[X]$ with $P(a) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

First, note that since $1 \in F$ is contained in every field, you have $F(a^4+a^2+1) = F(a^4+a^2)$.

In order to show this degree is finite you only need to prove that $a$ is algebraic over $F(a^4+a^2+1)$ right?

But this is clear because $a$ is the root of the polynomial
\begin{equation*}
X^4 + X^2 - (a^4+a^2) \in F(a^4+a^2)[X]
\end{equation*}

Note: If you don't want to supress the $1$, simply consider the polynomial
\begin{equation*}
X^4 + X^2 - (a^4+a^2+1)+1 \in F(a^4+a^2+1)[X]
\end{equation*}